# Map cannot zoom in a html div

Tags: android, html, maps, zooming

I added     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,target-densitydpi=medium-dpi,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">`     in all my pages.
I embeded a map in a div, and when I use an Android phone to test the map, I cannot zoom the map between different levels.
However, it works normally when I use an iPhone.
Is there any solution I can zoom map on Android devices, without removing the meta tag?